# how to add log traces for django's (1.11) URL dispatcher (not for production)

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging, django-views

I have an old (Django 1.11) over complicated Django application with overlapping and funnily ordered url matching rules and I want to update it to newer Django versions and to simplify / refactor.

For better understanding Id' like to navigate through the application (manually) and retrieve some traces

Would it be possible to achieve following without having to add log statements in every view.

I'd like to get traces telling me which rule was picked by the url dispatcher (and if possible, but not really necessary), which view with which parameter was called.

I'm for example sure, that some rules can just be deleted as they're no more used.

Example:
If I had following (not complicated with non overlapping rules) url dispacher rules.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^app1/', app1.views.top_view),
    url(r'^app1/a', app1.views.a_view),
]
```

and I acessed http://myserver/app1. I'd like to have a trace telling me, 
that `http://myserver/app1` triggered rule `^app1/` and (not so important) view `app1.views.top_view` will be used to handle the request.

midllewares, decorators, monkeypatches, whatever will do as long as I don't have to change all individual rules and  all views to get my traces.
Even a considerable performance hit is not an issue this is for debugging

P.S.

I am aware of the `django-extensions` module and the management command `show_urls`.

This is already helpful, but for more complicated urls showing up in my app I'd like to have the logging.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, maybe it was downvoted for that reason. But people should relax a bit. Sometimes the hardest thing about working with an immense framework like Django is not knowing where to start, because you never dug into those internals and getting a few pointers can lead to more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to upgrade to 2.2 first, or backport [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/79c196cfb287893aadc6b0e74603ffde1512170e#diff-b2f90a810a553411112f412de2a26617) else you can't get information from the router about the exact match it has used to resolve the request URI.

That said, it should be done in middleware during request phase. The ResolverMatch instance is available in the WSGIRequest as request.resolver_match. Using the fix above, it's trivial to add a log to each request.

If you cannot backport or upgrade, there is a way to do it, which basically involves building a cache on start up of all known urlconfs and then matching each one and I've done it at some point, yet don't have it laying around any more. You basically have to do the work of URLResolver.resolve() and then add the route to it, when it creates the ResolverMatch instance. Hopefully this helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks Melvyn, this might help. Will look into it.

Comment: I think you meant in the **response** phase?
At least for django 1.11 `request.resolver_match` is still `None`  during the **request** phase.

However:  I didn't to the backport so far to add `route` attribute, but I think this shouldn't alter this fact.

Comment: or perhaps (if using a class bases middleware) in `process_view()` ?

Comment: Found the answer in the doc:  `response` or `process_view()` will be fine:

An instance of ResolverMatch representing the resolved URL. This attribute is only set after URL resolving took place, which means it’s available in all views but not in middleware which are executed before URL resolving takes place (you can use it in process_view() though).

Comment: Since I was running the matching myself, I did it in request. I had to, because it was an API validating middleware, that matched api paths to API spec. If I couldn't find a path in the request stage, I would short circuit even before calling the view. But if process_view() works for you, then backport the patch and save yourself some work.

Comment: Ah OK, I see. Will try back porting 

Thanks again for your answer. It put me on the right track.First attempt of backporting failed. But I'm sure I can get it work with a little more effort and time

If not, I'll try upgrading.